# Ansible: How can I set serial numbers for hosts

Tags: jinja2, ansible, apache-zookeeper, ansible-inventory

I am trying to provision hosts on EC2, so I am working with Ansible Dynamic Inventory.

What I want to do is; to set serial number for each node.

**For example: "myid" configuration of Zookeeper**

Zookeeper requires serial number named "myid" for each node; 1 for hostA, 2 for hostB, 3 for hostC and so on.

Here is the part of my playbook that copies "myid" file to hosts.

```
- name: Set myid
  sudo: yes
  template: src=var/lib/zookeeper/myid.j2 dest=/var/lib/zookeeper/myid
```

And `myid.j2` should be something like this below.

```
{{ serial_number }}
```

**The question is: What should the variable "{{ serial_number }}" be like?**

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but perhaps you should use `ec2_facts` module to get the value of `instance-id` that is unique to each ec2 instance.

Comment: Each Zookeeper instance in the cluster requires a `myid` file that has a unique number between 1 and 255. The question is: when using dynamic inventory, how can an ansible script generate unique numbers, or count from 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by assigning a number to each EC2 instance as a tag when creating them. I then refer to that tag when creating the `myid` file. Below are the tasks I used to create my EC2 instances with all non-important fields left out for brevity.

```
- name: Launch EC2 instance(s)
  with_sequence: count="{{ instance_count }}"
  ec2:
    instance_tags:
      number: "{{ item }}"
```

Then when installing ZooKeeper on these servers, I use the dynamic inventory to obtain all the servers tagged with `zookeeper` and use the `number` tag in the `myid` file.

```
- name: Render and copy myid file
  copy: >
    content={{ ec2_tag_number }}
    dest=/etc/zookeeper/conf/myid
```

Note: when creating the EC2 instances, I needed to use `with_sequence` rather than the `count` field in the `ec2` module. Otherwise I wouldn't have an index to capture for the tag.

---

If you want the playbook to handle being able to add nodes to the current cluster, you can query for the number of EC2 instances tagged with `zookeeper` and add that to the iteration index. This is fine to have normally because `current_instance_count` will be 0 if there aren't any.

```
- name: Determine how many instances currently exist
  shell: echo "{{ groups['tag_zookeeper'] | length }}"
  register: current_instance_count
- name: Launch EC2 instance(s)
  with_sequence: count="{{ instance_count }}"
  ec2:
    instance_tags:
      number: "{{ item|int + current_instance_count.stdout|int }}"
```

Answer (score 7):

I found a nice clean way to do this using Ansible's with_index_items syntax:

```
tasks:
  - name: Set Zookeeper Id
    set_fact: zk_id={{item.0 + 1}}
    with_indexed_items: "{{groups['tag_Name_MESOS_MASTER']}}"
    when: item.1 == "{{inventory_hostname}}"
```

/etc/zookeeper/conf/myid template can then be set to

```
{{zk_id}}
```

This assumes you are using AWS dynamic inventory.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use template, you can directly assign the content of myid file in the playbook. Assume you have collect all ec2 instance into the group "ec2hosts".

```
- hosts: ec2hosts
  user: ubuntu
  sudo：Trues

  tasks:
    - name: Set Zookeeper Id
      copy: >
      content={{ item.0 + 1 }}
      dest=/var/lib/zookeeper/myid
      with_indexed_items: "{{groups['ec2hosts']}}"
      when: item.1 == "{{inventory_hostname}}"
```